# Publish asp.net web app in release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications, app-config

I have created asp.net web app in visual studio 2015
every thing is fine but when i'm trying to publish web app the configuration have only one option (debug) , i need to publish using release option,using method (file system).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/198pQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a3vm.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Profile` and create a other profile. There you can change other settings.

Comment: this screen contain 1 option "debug" only , i have release option , when create new debug configuration with release name i'm not show option of release to copy settings from it

Answer (score 0):

There is no Release option in Visual Studio Express